# Using Redis to store unique IDs as keys which hold a list of other keys

Tags: redis

I am looking to use redis to house a set of unique IDs (call them campaign_ids) and each campaign_id will have an array of promotional_ids to go along with them.

`{ 123: [345, 543] }` is an example of something I am trying to achieve, but I am just not sure how to set this up in Redis

Comment: The proper data type should be chosen according to how you're going to access the data. Storing the data in your example is very easy (e.g. using a Set), but how are you planning to fetch is the real question. If, for example, you want to access campaign IDs by a specific promotional ID, you'll need to enrich the data you're managing to support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there isn't simple answer to this because Redis data structures should be designed by the way you use them.

For example you could use [Sets](http://redis.io/commands#set):

```
SADD 123 345
SADD 123 543
SMEMBERS 123
1) "345"
2) "543"
SREM 123 345
SMEMBERS 123
1) "543"
```

Comment: Thanks @Mino! I wound up using your suggestion